# PHP strip_tags: allow just first tag

Tags: php

I have this code `strip_tags($html,'<a>,<br>')` that strips all tags except `<a>` and `<br>`

How can I strip all `<a>` tags except first? Is there something like `strip_tags($html,'<a>[0],<br>')`?

HTML example:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="#">I want this link</a><br/>
        Something in new line with unwantend <a href="#">link</a><br/>
        Lorem ipsum bla bla...<br/>
        Unwanted <a href="#">link</a> once more.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you will have to write some code to do that, perhaps a regular expresssion

Comment: @Dagon ok thanks. I thought maybe there is shorter way of doing that.

Comment: @Dagon [The pony, he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: @SpacePeasant there might be if we knew he context

Comment: @Machavity [we all want a pony](https://memegenerator.net/instance/64263060)

Answer (score 1):

EDITED from original answer:

you can use preg_replace and a loop

```
 $ret = preg_match_all('/<a>/',$html,$matches);
   for ($a = count($matches); $a>=1 ;$a--){
      $str = preg_replace('/<a>/',"",$str,$a);
   }
```

Comment: thats not what the OP is asking

Comment: all good... :-) just beware how dangerous messing with html via regular expressions can be