# One website - multiple database

Tags: php, mysql

We have multiple masters that are synced into a slave. We have decided to create a database for each master (let say MDB0001; MDB0002; MDB0003, etc...). This will allow to not corrupt the entire database if one replication fails or has corrupted data... The slave is used to show information to the people that are on the web (the master is only available in the local network)

The purpose is: we want to have a website (in php) on the server (slave) that shows the content for each database depending who is logged in. So if the user  MDB0001 is connected, we have to read the data from the database MDB0001.

How can this be done? Is it a good way to do that? Or, do I have to duplicate the website for each database?

I hope I'm clear in my explanation. Thanks

Comment: what? you have a database per user ? How many users do you have?

Comment: this is not me who has decided... currently, we have 2 databases. But each time the system will be sold, a new database will be created. My first thought was to create one database for each master with different primary key (unique key + autoincrement) then it will be replicated in the same database. But the technician said that it will be easier and more secure to have them separately for the replication. It is still time to change our mind. This part of the system is not yet created. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: Get ready for a maintenance nightmare when you have 5000 customers.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you get a variable from the login you could put a key->value array together on your db.php page;

```
 $userDBs = array('login1'=>'db1','login2'=>'db2');

 $dbName = $userDBs[$loggedinID];  // if login1 logs in, db1 would be result.

  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbName, 'someUser', 'somePass');
```

or have a seperate db for the associations:

```
  $sel = "Select dbName from databases where userId='".$loggedInID."'";
  $stmt = $db->query($sel);
  while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
      $dbName = $r['dbName'];
  }

 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbName, 'someUser', 'somePass');
```

Comment: i dont see how this is an answer to the question asked

Comment: lol, you are all over me tonight.  He asked that if login1 logs in, they use db1, if login2 logs in they use db2, am i mistaken?

Comment: sorry if it looks that way, i think i was more focused on the replication issue, which is not actually asked about.

Comment: no worries.  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622736/php-strip-tags-allow-just-first-tag/40623084#40623084 and see if you concur.